# How duplicate an object in a list and update property of duplicated objects?

Tags: c#, .net

What would be the best way to duplicate an object placed in a list of items and change a property of duplicated objects ?

I thought proceed in the following manner:
- get object in the list by "ref" + "article"
- Cloned the found object as many times as desired (n times)
- Remove the object found
- Add the clones in the list

What do you think?

A concrete example:

```
Private List<Product> listProduct;
listProduct= new List<Product>();

Product objProduit_1 = new Produit;

objProduct_1.ref = "001";
objProduct_1.article = "G900";
objProduct_1.quantity = 30;

listProducts.Add(objProduct_1);

ProductobjProduit_2 = new Product;

objProduct_2.ref = "002";
objProduct_2.article = "G900";
objProduct_2.quantity = 35;

listProduits.Add(objProduct_2);
```

desired method:

```
public void updateProductsList(List<Product> paramListProducts,Produit  objProductToUpdate, int32 nbrDuplication, int32 newQuantity){       
...      
}
```

Calling method example:

```
 updateProductsList(listProducts,objProduct_1,2,15);
```

Waiting result:

Replace follow object :

```
ref = "001";
article = "G900";
quantite = 30;
```

By:

```
ref = "001";
article = "G900";
quantite = 15;

ref = "001";
article = "G900";
quantite = 15;
```

The Algorithm is correct? Would you have an idea of the method implementation "updateProductsList"

Thank you in advance for your help.

Comment: it is C#, sorry! I've delete the java flag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, it looks like you want to implement your own `ProductList` object. The implementation is simple, when extending `List<Product>`. Second, to update the product, you can remove the old product, clone it twice and add it twice.

```
public class ProductList : List<Product> {
    public void update(Product product, int nrOfDuplications, int newQuantity) {
       Remove(product);
       for(int i = 0; i < nrOfDuplications; i++) {
           Add(new Product() {
               ref = product.ref,
               article = product.article,
               quantity = newQuantity
           });
       }
    }
}
```

This could be further improved by using a [copy constructor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_constructor), which means that you don't need the complete list of all the parts.

Comment: thank you for your reply, I actually caught your solution. Just out of curiosity is there a pattern corresponding to my needs?
Better than duplicate object for only one property to change.
Thank you